# Swagger formdata fails to convert dto from type "String" to selected DTO type without defined converter

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I am having the following controller

```
@Validated
@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/api/example", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> create(@Valid @ModelAttribute ExampleDto exampleDto) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("OK");
    }
}
```

Dtos:

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class ExampleDto {

    NestedExampleDto exampleDto;
    private MultipartFile icon;

}

@Setter
@Getter
public class NestedExampleDto {
    String title;
}
```

After I try to execute the swagger interface:

[image]

I got the following error:

[image]

If I add a custom converter, it works. But isn't there a way to go arround this and configure how swagger makes the form-data/multi-part requests or just by default use Jackson or other serialization tool?